# Android studio java getting error fetching access token

Tags: java, instagram-api

```
package com.yazilimevi.unfollow.CustomViews;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.yazilimevi.unfollow.InsClient;
import com.yazilimevi.unfollow.MainActivity;
import com.yazilimevi.unfollow.R;
import com.yazilimevi.unfollow.insterfaces.AuthenticationListener;

public class AuthenticationDialog extends Dialog {
    private AuthenticationListener listener;
    private Context context;
    private WebView webView;

    private final String url = InsClient.BASE_URL
            +"oauth/authorize/?client_id="
            +InsClient.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID
            +"&redirect_uri="
            +InsClient.REDIRECT_URI
            +"&response_type=token"
            +"&display=touch&scope=public_content";


    public AuthenticationDialog(AuthenticationListener listener, @NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.auth_dialog);
        initializeWebView();
    }

    private void initializeWebView() {
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            String access_token;
            boolean authComplete;

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
              /*  WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
                settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);*/
                if (url.contains("#access_token=") && !authComplete){

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    access_token = uri.getEncodedFragment();
                    access_token = access_token.substring(access_token.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
                    authComplete = true;
                    listener.onCodeReceived(access_token);
                    dismiss();
                }
                else if (url.contains("?error")){
                    System.out.println("çıktı");
                    dismiss();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

url.contains("#access_token=") It translates to false and Instagram webview does not work. I added Instagram API and client ids. I call the dialog in the main activity section, but only the Instagram logo appears in the dialog that opens. url.contains("#access_token=") It translates to false and Instagram webview does not work. I added Instagram API and client ids. I call the dialog in the main activity section, but only the Instagram logo appears in the dialog that opens. url.contains("#access_token=") It translates to false and Instagram webview does not work. I added Instagram API and client ids. I call the dialog in the main activity section, but only the Instagram logo appears in the dialog that opens.

```
`public static final String GET_USER_INFO_URL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=";
public static String INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID ="685551893072923";
public static String INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID_SECRET ="7b599f18f96677b83053241599686f42";
public static String BASE_URL ="https://api.instagram.com/";
public static String REDIRECT_URI = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com/";
public final static String PREF_NAME = "app_pref";`
```

I'm waiting for your help I'm waiting for your help I'm waiting for your help I'm waiting for your help